# SQL Server: How to use substring in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have this kind of row:

> ```
> [Arturo Ochando]  <20>
> ```

But i want only:

> ```
> Arturo Ochando
> ```

How can i do that ?

And how use this in a 'select' operation ?

**update:**
i would like to find the first and the last '[' ']' and catch only what is inside there.

Example:

> voice: English version)  [Cobalt Claw]

return

> Cobalt Claw

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get text between first `[` and next `]`.

```
-- cte for test data
;with actor_character(character) AS
(
  select 'voice: English version) [Cobalt Claw]' union all
  select 'voice: English version) [Cobalt Claw' union all
  select 'voice: English version)  Cobalt Claw]' union all
  select 'voice: English version) ]Cobalt Claw[' union all
  select 'voice: English version)  Cobalt Claw'
)
select *,
  case
    -- Test for not valid positions
    when Start.Pos = 1 or Stop.Pos = 0
    then character
    else substring(character, Start.Pos, Stop.Pos-Start.Pos)
  end
from actor_character
  cross apply (select charindex('[', character)+1) as Start(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(']', character, Start.Pos)) as Stop(Pos)
```

Get text between first `[` and last `]`.

```
-- cte for test data
;with actor_character(character) AS
(
  select 'voice: English version) [Cobalt Claw]' union all
  select 'voice: English version) [Cobalt Claw' union all
  select 'voice: English version)  Cobalt Claw]' union all
  select 'voice: English version) ]Cobalt Claw[' union all
  select 'voice: English version) [Cobalt]Claw]' union all
  select 'voice: English version)  Cobalt Claw'
)
select *,
  case
    -- Test for not valid positions
    when Start.Pos = 0 or Stop.Pos = 0 or Start.Pos > len(character)-Stop.Pos
    then character
    else substring(character, Start.Pos+1, len(character)-Stop.Pos-Start.Pos)
  end

from actor_character
  cross apply (select charindex('[', character)) as Start(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(']', reverse(character))) as Stop(Pos)
```

Comment: Nice: How would you update this to find the last ']' (See the update in the question)?

Comment: @Jon – Added a version to use last `]` instead.

Comment: Would I be able to take a column in the query and get a substring of that column in the same select statement?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a regular expression, to get the data you need out of your source string.

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html

http://blog.tech-cats.com/2007/09/using-regular-expression-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(field, charindex('[', field) + 1, charindex(']', field) - charindex('[', field) - 1)
```

Comment: @squawknull this <20> came together with the row, the database was not mine.

Comment: I see.  So it's part of the string.  I'll revise my query.

Comment: i try what you recommend, but now working here's my case:
SELECT TOP (50) substring(character, charindex('[', character) + 1, charindex(']', character) - charindex('[', character) - 1) FROM actor_character

Comment: returns:Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 2

Comment: Does every single row have both the "[" and "]" characters?

Comment: something doesn't seem right.  Try running the following two queries to see what rows might be causing a problem:

Comment: select charindex('[', field) + 1 lindex, * from ??? where lindex < 1 or lindex > len(field)

Comment: select charindex(']', field) - charindex('[', field) - 1 length, * from ??? where length < 1 or length + charindex('[', field) + 1 > length (field)